# How do I find the Obol vendor with items my level?

Tags: diablo-iv

In Diablo 4 you can gamble your [Obols](https://diablo4.purediablo.com/Murmuring_Obols) with [vendors](https://diablo4.purediablo.com/Purveyor_of_Curiosities) in many of the major towns. However they always seem to have items which are much lower level than my character.

I guess I can gamble for legendary affixes, but occasionally these vendors have some gold bordered items which are your current level.

Screengrab from a YouTube video.

[image: purveyor of curiosities with gold border items]

Is there a way to know which vendor this is? Does it work on a rotation? Or do I have to just go visit every Obol vendor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some research into this seems to have thrown up that it was a visual UI bug, and that the items should not be giving away their rarity.

It was actually fixed as part of the 1.0.3 patch, under the UI heading. The YouTube video I screen grabbed was from June 6.

> Fixed an issue where the Purveyor of Curiosities’ menu would erroneously display item quality on some items (this didn’t affect what item quality was available to gamble for).

Patch notes page, https://news.blizzard.com/en-us/diablo4/23964909/diablo-iv-patch-notes you have to scroll down to 1.0.3